# ¿ Como averiguar el tiempo transcurrido?

Tags: javascript

Hola quería sacar los años, meses, semanas, días y horas, segundos que han pasado desde una fecha. He conseguido lo que se muestra a continuación, pero no se sacar la cuenta exacta, ni consigo ir restando el tiempo de años, meses, semanas, días, etc... por lo que siempre me sale lo que ha pasado. Osea me pone los años que han pasado, los meses que han pasado, etc... y yo quiero que me salgan los años y el resto de meses, días, horas y segundos.  (Ejemplo: 30 años, 2 meses, 1 semana, 3 días, 6 horas, 28 minutos, 15 segundos  )

```js
var nacimiento = new Date(1936, 11, 29)
var hoy = new Date

var tiempoPasado= new Date() - nacimiento

//calculo segundos 
var segundos = tiempoPasado/ 1000

var minutos = segundos / 60
tiempoPasado= tiempoPasado- (minutos - segundos)

var horas = minutos / 60
tiempoPasado= tiempoPasado- ( horas - minutos)

var dias = horas / 24
tiempoPasado= tiempoPasado- (dias - horas)


var meses = dias / 30.416666666666668
tiempoPasado= tiempoPasado- (meses - dias)

var anos = meses / 12

console.log(`Han pasado ${anos} años, ${meses} meses,  ${dias} dias, ${horas} horas, y ${minutos} minutos desde que naciste. Ya chocheas...!!`)
```

Comment: Saludos, [Aqui esta la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210749/8933039) a tu pregunta, solo debes traduciar el código, es una muy buena respuesta y tienes mas informacion [aqui tambien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633001/8933039)  y [este otro enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406310/8933039) puede ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias, pero no encuentro la forma para poder sacar los errores de mi código. Gracias @J.Rodríguez

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para realizar el calculo de forma correcta, debes empezar calculando el total de años transcurridos, luego restar los años al tiempo transcurrido, y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a los segundos.

#### Ejemplo:

Considerando que `new Date(1936, 11, 29)`, es igual al `29/12/1936`...

```js
var nacimiento = new Date(1936, 11, 29)
var hoy = new Date()

var tiempoPasado= hoy - nacimiento
var segs = 1000;
var mins = segs * 60;
var hours = mins * 60;
var days = hours * 24;
var months = days * 30.416666666666668;
var years = months * 12;

//calculo 
var anos = Math.floor(tiempoPasado / years);

tiempoPasado = tiempoPasado - (anos * years);
var meses = Math.floor(tiempoPasado / months)

tiempoPasado = tiempoPasado - (meses * months);
var dias = Math.floor(tiempoPasado / days)

tiempoPasado = tiempoPasado - (dias * days);
var horas = Math.floor(tiempoPasado / hours)

tiempoPasado = tiempoPasado - (horas * hours);
var minutos = Math.floor(tiempoPasado / mins)

tiempoPasado = tiempoPasado - (minutos * mins);
var segundos = Math.floor(tiempoPasado / segs)

console.log(`Han pasado ${anos} años, ${meses} meses,  ${dias} dias, ${horas} horas, y ${minutos} minutos desde que naciste. Ya chocheas...!!`)
```

Comment: Eso es amigo, claro como para salirme las cuentas... Gracias @Marcos

Answer (score 1):

Osea que entonces necesitas que los segundos se vayan actualizando "en tiempo real  y cada vez que  pasen 60 segundos se sumen un minuto y cada  minutos una hora y así progresivamente ?

Para ello puedes usar setTimeout para que la función se ejecute cada segundo a manera de reloj

Y otra cosa cual es la intención en decrementar la variable timepoPasado?

no he probado  bien tu código pero me parece que algunas cuentas están mal.

Comment: Esto tiene pinta de comentario, y no una respuesta como tal, deberías reconsiderar colocar esto como un comentario, o editar la respuesta.

Comment: No @Missael Armenta , lo que quiero es descubrir el error de mi código, para saber los años, meses, días, horas y segundos desde una fecha. No hace falta que se actualice, pues cada vez que haga un console.log , se actualizara solo. Solo que a mi me salen los todos los años, todos los meses, todos los días, todas las horas...desde la fecha en cuestión...No se si me explico. Me sale, por ejemplo: 2 años, 24 meses, 730 dias... Y se trata de sacar el tiempo pasado, :1 año, 11 meses, 256 dias, tres horas y 6 segundos...